# Changing "User Name" hidden my account, how can I return it?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

The account in Windows 7 64 bit on my notebook was occasionally named not as I usually prefer ("Toshiba", chosen by the shop manager without asking me), so after some time I renamed it to another (Myname) in Control panel. As known, it's not actual renaming, but changing "Full name" that will be used for login instead of "User Name". The folder is still named "Toshiba")

After that when I was logged in as "Myname" I looked at classic [control userpasswords2] dialog and noticed that the properties of the account allows editing both, so I changed "User Name" field from Toshiba to Myname to match "Full Name" so they both become Myname. So starting that what happened (no restart):

- After pressing ok for Properties dialog this account disappeared from the [control userpasswords2] dialog list.
- User account in "Control Panel" started showing the blank icon for my current account and dialogs about changing anything even didn't contain labels for fields. I decided not to edit them.
- I quickly created a new admin account and restarted. I didn't see my Toshiba/Myname account as a choice for login so logged in as the new admin.

Now I have this renamed account listed in [control userpasswords2] as Myname/Myname, safely existing c:\Users\Toshiba folder, Windows NT\ProfileList\ entry in the registry pointing to c:\Users\Toshiba.

What should I do to return my account safely? Should I also report this as a bug?

Comment: What you describe is not a bug.

Comment: Rather than messing around with renaming accounts and folders, you might be better off creating a new user account with the name you want then transferring all your data to it from the original.

Answer (score 2):

I would always do user management in `lusrmgr.msc`. Only there you have full control of a user account. Also, when you rename an account, it doesn't change the name of the profile directory. The (IMHO) best way to clean up your issue is:

- log in as Administrator (you probably have to enable the account first and set a password)
- delete the renamed user account (**not** its profile folder)
- create a new user account with the correct name
- log into the new account to create a new profile folder, then log off again
- log in as Administrator again
- copy (don't move!) your files from the old profile folder to the new profile folder (if you get `permission denied` at this point, you have to take ownership first)
- log in as the new user again and check if you can access your files all right

When everything is working, you can delete the old profile (in the search box type `view advanced system settings` and press `enter`, then click `Settings...` in the `User Profiles` box, select the profile that says *Account Unknown* and click `Delete`).

You will have to do your account's configuration over with this procedure, but you'll have a clean account and profile afterwards.

Comment: Forgot to mention it's home premium, so no lusrmgr.msr working. If I delete account from netplwiz (aka Control userpasswords2), will it leave the profile folder intact? The problem is that the renamed account only listed here and absent from Control Panel accounts

Comment: Just follow the steps outline in this thread: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/activating-administrator-on-windows-7-home-premium/74209f8d-e9f2-4db7-994f-dfc242969025?auth=1 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to login finally and posting this just for others who might face the same problem and find this question with web-search.

I noticed that the renamed account that I see only in netplwiz (aka Control userpasswords2) has only HomeUsers group listed (Group Membership tab), so I changed it to be full administrator (and after that managed see it in the welcome screen and to login.

Probably this is a misbehavior of Windows Home Premium 64 bit, but reporting it would be a hard task with my notebook OEM-only technical support. Anyway, be careful when using netplwiz